# How to focus an "a" tag created dynamically?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to let an "a" tag focused after it has been created by an ajax call.

the code is the following:

```
    <form method="post" id="submitrow">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input name="quantity" id="id_quantity" />
                </td>
                <td>$
                    <input name="price" id="id_price" />
                </td>
                <td><span id="add_row"></span>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

    <script>
    jQuery("#id_quantity").change(function () {
        jQuery('#add_row').html('<a onclick="document.forms[\'submitrow\'].submit();" id="sbmbtn">click me</a>');

        jQuery('#sbmbtn').focus(); // I want to focus the new link, it does not works

        alert(jQuery('#sbmbtn').is(':focus')); // it should be True!

        jQuery('#sbmbtn').live("keyup", function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                alert('whoot whoot!');
            }
        });
    });

    jQuery("#id_quantity").focus();
    </script>
```

It seems the DOM is not correctly updated after the html replacement. Maybe I have to replace the code in a different way?

I've create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S6zz4/) with a simplified version of my code that reproduces the problem.

Thanks in advance for any hint provided! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set tabindex on **a** tag

```
jQuery("#id_quantity").change(function () {
    jQuery('#add_row').html('<a tabindex="11" onclick="document.forms[\'submitrow\'].submit();" id="sbmbtn">click me</a>');

    jQuery('#sbmbtn').focus(); // I want to focus the new link, it does not works

    alert(jQuery('#sbmbtn').is(':focus')); // it should be True!

    jQuery('#sbmbtn').live("keyup", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            alert('whoot whoot!');
        }
    });
});

jQuery("#id_quantity").focus();
```

Comment: However, it will alert true.

Comment: @Nix - I mean, with the current code, if you set a tab index, change the input, it alerts "true" (as in, it has focus). see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S6zz4/1/

Comment: You are right, i posted this earlier, and thought it only worked with tab ;) .  Just retested and it works.

Comment: @franz-sundal Thank you! You hit the spot... I didn't know I had to have a tabindex in order to set the focus!

Comment: @furins: It happens that if you focus div or a without tabindex it didnt work. I face the same problem and tabindex solve my issue too.